# Android: laying out a simple stack of boxes?

Tags: android, android-layout

This should be easy, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.
I want to make a flud stack of boxes, as in this picture:

```
+------------------+
| +------o-------+ |
| |  Banner      | |
| +------o-------+ |
| | Buttons      | |
| |              | |
| +------o-------+ |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| | ViewFlipper  | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| |              | |
| +------o-------+ |
| | Buttons      | |
| +------o-------+ |
| | Footer       | |
| +------o-------+ |
+------------------+
```

Every box - including the outer one - represents a Layout containing other widgets (or even, a lone widget). The outer box matches the device's width and height. The width and height of the stack must match the outer container. The edges of the boxes are glued to each other and to the top and bottom edges of the container, as indicated by the 'o's.  All the inner layouts wrap their content tightly, except the largest - a ViewFlipper - which contains a scrollable listbox and can expand or contract as needed. The number of boxes is not important, as long as it is four or more.

The ViewFlipper contains a number of vertical LinearLayouts with width/height=fillparent (where my understanding is that the parent is the ViewFlipper).

In my attempts so far, I have had some success with an outer RelativeLayout and  stitching the edges of the internal boxes with:
`android:layout_below="@+id/former_box` and `android:layout_above="@+id/following_box`, but it is an instable situation in which the boxes start acting weird (such as the second one covering entirely the others, etc.) every time I change the design (by, for instance, inserting another intermidiate box). Please note, that this is a design-time layout, no fancy dynamic run-time rearrangements are involved.

I am now experimenting with TableLayout (a single column) with basically no joy worth reporting. I am obviously not an Android expert, but still. What is the best way to do this?

**Edit - insert actual code**
Since it appears that omitting the actual code fogged the issue (I hoped it would clarify it, my mistake) I am inserting the working version here. You will notice it lacks the banner and footer. As mentioned above, every time I try to insert additional boxes it blows up on me - circular references starring often.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        tools:context=".TomActivity" >

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/spinnerbox"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:onClick="left"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/leftarrow"
    android:background="#888888"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:minHeight="0dip"
        android:minWidth="0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"       
        android:onClick="left"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/spintitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftarrow"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightarrow"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/leftarrow"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/rightarrow"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Label" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/rightarrow"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:minHeight="0dip"
    android:minWidth="0dip"
    android:onClick="right"
    android:text="Button" 
    />

  </RelativeLayout>


  <ViewFlipper
      android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
      android:layout_margin="0dip"      
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerbox"
      android:layout_above="@+id/buttonbox"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="0dip"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

      <ListView
      android:id="@+id/CoursesView"
      android:layout_margin="0dip"      
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
      </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="0dip"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

      <ListView
      android:id="@+id/FutureCoursesView"
      android:layout_margin="0dip"
      android:background="#ffffff"      
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
      </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="0dip"        
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

      <ListView
      android:id="@+id/MessagesView"
      android:layout_margin="0dip"
      android:background="#ffffff"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" >
      </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>     
  </ViewFlipper>

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/buttonbox"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/CurrentCoursesButton"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/FutureCoursesButton"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/UnreadMessagesButton"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/RefreshButton"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="refreshAll"
    android:text="Button" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/LogoffButton"
    android:background="#888888"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="logOff"
    android:text="Button" />


  </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Cheers,

***Edited to show the layout more clearly and give info on the rationale***

Comment: What is wrong with wrapping the children boxes with a vertical LinearLayout?

Comment: When I do, the large widget (a ViewFlipper) ends up on top of everything that is below. That is why I turned to the RelativeLayout originally.

Comment: A ViewFlipper is used to show one view (out of a number of views) at a time. I didn't mean using a LinearLayout as the outer view, but wrapping the inner boxes inside a vertical LinearLayout

Comment: Is this what you want https://gist.github.com/luksprog/6549402?

Comment: It is - except that, when I add my vertical linearlayout inside the viewflipper, (fillparetn in both directions) they overlap the top widgets (banner ad buttons).

Comment: You're using some useless attributes(like the gravity on the `LinearLayouts` and the weight on the `ListView`(as you could simply set the ListView's height to match_parent)). The `ViewFlipper`'s height should be `wrap_content`, also the order in which you place the compoenents in the outer `RelativeLayout`(see the order in my gist).

Comment: The useless attributes come from the constant layout churn/test/edit of the layout - they should however, be harmless, isn't it? You are right about wrap_content (changing it does not appear to have any noticeable effect, however) The order, I guess, is wrong (witness the circular dependencies that hit me now and then) however what would the correct order be? Listing the widgets top to bottom (what I did) seems the natural thing to do. I see you followed a different principle, but which one and why beats me. (Besides that example is still not what I need, see my comment below)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand were do you have problems. Adding extra stuff to your already present layout shouldn't break things. At the same link as above https://gist.github.com/luksprog/6549402 I've inserted two buttons as the banner and footer and they work with no problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When building complex/multilevel layouts, prepare your innermost layout first. Then wrap your outer layouts around the innermost one iteratively. This way, decisions like which layout container to use get a bit simplified.

See if the following looks like what you are looking for:

[image]

I have posted the Layout's xml here: [Link(pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/ptt44ggG) [Link(file)](http://ge.tt/1VFbl7s/v/0?c)

What I have done is use the layout you provided and placed it inside a LinearLayout with vertical orientation. The top and bottom "banners" are given `layout_weight="0"` while the content area(code that you have given) has a `layout_weight` set to `1`. So, the top and bottom banners take a fixed amount of space, and the content takes up the rest.

Answer (score 3):

I think LinearLayout will be best for you...

please try and let me know if you find any difficulty

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/spinnerbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="left">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/leftarrow"
                android:background="#888888"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:minHeight="0dip"
                android:minWidth="0dip"
                android:onClick="left"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/spintitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Label" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rightarrow"
                android:background="#888888"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="0dip"
                android:minWidth="0dip"
                android:onClick="right"
                android:text="Button"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/CoursesView"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/FutureCoursesView"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/MessagesView"
                    android:layout_margin="0dip"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CurrentCoursesButton"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/FutureCoursesButton"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/UnreadMessagesButton"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/RefreshButton"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="refreshAll"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/LogoffButton"
            android:background="#888888"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="logOff"
            android:text="Button" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, your `ViewFlipper` is appearing at the top of a scrollable container. If it resides inside a `ScrollView`, you can instruct its contents to fill the viewport by using `android:fillViewport="true"`:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

    <ViewFlipper
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</ScrollView>
```

If you have multiple items inside the `ScrollView`, use it inside a `LinearLayout` in conjunction with `android:layout_weight`:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ViewFlipper
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I added my current code to the question. ScrollViews are not part of the (outer) layout

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your `ViewFlipper` shouldn't have `"fill_parent"` for its height. In a `RelativeLayout`, that really does mean "fill the parent".

If I were you, I'd switch to a `LinearLayout`, like others have mentioned. To do this, simply give all of your *other* "block" components a height of `"wrap_content"`. For your `ViewFlipper`, you want a combination of `layout_height="0dp"` and `layout_weight="1"`. This will tell it to simply expand in all the remaining space, without overlapping.

Then, since you're using a `LinearLayout`, get rid of all the `_align` and `above`/`below` tags. They don't do anything for a linear layout, and it makes it ridiculously hard to read.

One other thing: When doing semi-complicated layouts like this, it's often helpful to break each "block" out into a separate XML file. You can then include each piece in the "main" layout, and everything looks much better. It helps you work on one piece at a time, without having to scroll through a 500-line layout file.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <Banner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Buttons
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >
        <!-- Any views you want here, they can't overflow the ViewFlipper -->
    </ViewFlipper>
    <Buttons
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Footer
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I love the idea of using include for layout pieces. How is it done?

Comment: The basics are here: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 2):

As **Geobits** suggested separates the views into separate XML files.I have made complete view as you wanted.just check it.I have used weightSum so that it can fill whole screen.

**main_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="10"
  >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ababab"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#ababab"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

     <include layout="@layout/button_row" />  

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="6"
    >

    <!-- Page Container -->
    <ViewFlipper
       android:id="@+id/vfPageContainer"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       >

        <include layout="@layout/view_one" />

        <!-- You can add more layouts here. -->

    </ViewFlipper>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#ababab"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

     <include layout="@layout/button_row" /> 

</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ababab"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    >

     <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**button_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
 >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CurrentCoursesButton"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/FutureCoursesButton"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/UnreadMessagesButton"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/RefreshButton"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="refreshAll"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogoffButton"
        android:background="#888888"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="logOff"
        android:text="Button" />


 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**view_one.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/MessagesView"
      android:background="#ffffff"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >
  </ListView>
</LinearLayout>     

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack up your views with property

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

for all the child in RelativeLayout,
and you can set child view's height and width and even margins individually

Comment: That - setting a fixed width/height - is exactly what i do not want to do. I want the content to determine the height of the boxes (except for the largest, as explained) and the edges should adjust "flowing" - except for the topmost and bottom-most.

Answer (score 1):

**Just use a LinearLayout as Outter.** With orientantion Vertical. 
Every child inside it, should be width="match_parent" height="wrap_content"

Doesnt matter which kind of view are the childs inside the Outter.

Comment: When I do, the large widget (a ViewFlipper) ends up on top of everything that is below. That is why I turned to the RelativeLayout originally.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? But I guess the problem is that you should set proper layout params on the views you're using in the view flipper.

Comment: I will, as soon as I figure out how to add images in this wiki. In the meantime, I have edited the question to give more detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TomActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/spinnerbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:onClick="left">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/leftarrow"
                    android:background="#888888"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:minHeight="0dip"
                    android:minWidth="0dip"
                    android:onClick="left"
                    android:text="Button" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/spintitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Label" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/rightarrow"
                    android:background="#888888"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="0dip"
                    android:minWidth="0dip"
                    android:onClick="right"
                    android:text="Button"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/CoursesView"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/FutureCoursesView"
                        android:layout_margin="0dip"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/MessagesView"
                        android:layout_margin="0dip"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ViewFlipper>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttonbox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/CurrentCoursesButton"
                android:background="#888888"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/FutureCoursesButton"
                android:background="#888888"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/UnreadMessagesButton"
                android:background="#888888"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/RefreshButton"
                android:background="#888888"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="refreshAll"
                android:text="Button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/LogoffButton"
                android:background="#888888"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="logOff"
                android:text="Button" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```